# Word 2010 Updating Table of Contents

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying make a change to a heading in my document, when I go to the Table of Contents tab to update table it does not give me the option to Update Page Numbers Only or Entire Table, it automatically removes all of my page numbers from the TOC and does not even add the change I made to the actual heading.  Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: You can try opening the print preview, then going back to the document. This tends to update fields here there and everywhere. Also, is it still a smart field? If you accidentally convert it to text it will no longer update.

Comment: I made the change in the heading and went to print preview and that did not work. Should I be making my change to the heading in the actual TOC or in the actual document?

Comment: I tried making the change in the body of the document (heading) and in the actual TOC and when I click update table, I do not get any option to update page numbers only or entire table.  I created a TOC a few weeks prior and was getting the option, not sure what happened from then until now.

Comment: Automatically generated TOC are only updated, not edited. In other words, you must edit headings in the document, not in the TOC. If you tried editing them in the TOC, you may have messed up the coding that generates the fields of the table. Try Victoria Jilote's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

When I added Table of Contents to my document, I did it last. You may have to delete the TOC you have in there now and redo. The TOC should then be correct with the updated titles.